# Adjust Hours on UTC String to Account for TimeZoneOffset

Tags: typescript

I have a library that provides a time-picker HTML element, which takes a UTC string as an input. The timepicker adjusts any UTC string it receives to local time. So, for example, if it takes `'0001-01-01T17:00:00.000Z'` in, it will show the time as 12pm, not 5pm, since it subtracts 5 . I am working off the assumption that it's impossible to form a Javascript Date object as the UTC string I want.

Method I need: `public adjustUtcStringToAccountForLocalOffSet(utcTime: string): string`
Sample input: `'0001-01-01T17:00:00.000Z'`
Sample output (in EST timezone): `'0001-01-01T17:00:00.000Z'`
Random note: Time needs to be in 24 hour format, but I do NOT care about the date, since the timepicker only returns a time. So if offset is -5 from 02 hrs, result should be 24-2 = 22; date does NOT need to adjust.

```
class Tester {

  const lengthOfUtcHourSegment: number = 2;

  public adjustUtcStringToAccountForLocalOffSet(utcTime: string): string {
    let dt = new Date(utcTime);
    let currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours: number = dt.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
    let startOfHourSegmentIdx: number = utcTime.indexOf('T') + 1;
    let endOfHourSegmentIdx: number = startOfHourSegmentIdx + this.lengthOfUtcHourSegment;
    let utcHourSegment: string = utcTime.substring(startOfHourSegmentIdx, endOfHourSegmentIdx);
    let adjustedHourSegment: string = this.adjustHourSegmentForOffset(utcHourSegment, currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours).toString();
    let utcStringAsArray: string[] = utcTime.split('');
    utcStringAsArray.splice(startOfHourSegmentIdx, this.lengthOfUtcHourSegment, adjustedHourSegment);
    let adjustedUtcString: string = utcStringAsArray.join('');

    console.log(adjustedUtcString); //Here for testing

    return adjustedUtcString;
  }

  private adjustHourSegmentForOffset(hours: number, localOffSetInHrs: number): number{
    let adjustedHours: number = hours - localOffSetInHrs;
    adjustedHours = this.ensureTimeIsInTwentyFourHourFormat(adjustedHours);
    return adjustedHours;
  }

  private ensureTimeIsInTwentyFourHourFormat(hours: number): hours {
    if (hours < 0 ){
      hours = 24 - Math.abs(hours);
    }

    return hours;
  }

  constructor() {}
}


//Testing code
let tester = new Tester();
tester.adjustUtcStringToAccountForLocalOffSet('0001-01-01T02:00:00.000Z'); //should return 21 in EST 
tester.adjustUtcStringToAccountForLocalOffSet('0001-01-01T17:00:00.000Z'); //should return 12 in EST
tester.adjustUtcStringToAccountForLocalOffSet('0001-01-01T24:00:00.000Z'); //should return 19 in EST
```

[Link to Working Code](https://jsbin.com/xifamekije/edit?js,console)

Comment: Thanks, just any general errors in my code, things you would differently. My understanding of this site was "Look at my code, tell me what's garbage". Or is it more for narrowly-focused optimization?

Comment: I don't have time for a full review right now, Friday possibly, but the desired output is fundamentally wrong. The `Z` in your date means UTC time zone. If you want to specify a timezone replace the `Z` with an offset, for example `0001-01-01T17:00:00.000+07:00`. [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime). Your assumption was incorrect, so that might eliminate the need for this review altogether :)

Comment: @Gerrit0: Yes, that's something I didn't know - I might delete this since I missed something so obvious. Thank you!